# How to use wp_enqueue_style() and wp_enqueue_script() only when needed?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, wp-head

My plugin uses wp_enqueue_style() and wp_enqueue_script() to load resources, but I have kept in mind not to degrade the performance for the user and only load these when the current set of posts contain the shortcode for my plugin. I do this by using:

```
add_filter('the_posts', 'CrayonWP::the_posts');
```

the_posts is called before wp_head, but it is also called a few times afterwards (probably for recent posts in the widgets etc).

The problem here is that when I am searching the post contents for my shortcode and signalling the enqueuing process, there are times when:

- the_post is called before wp_head (what I want)
- but that set of posts does not have my shortcode and I don't enqueue.
- later on, another call to the_posts tries to enqueue but it's too late.

Is there a definite way to check what will appear on a page before wp_head is called so that I can be confident that I will enqueue only when needed but not miss the opportunity?

**EDIT:**

Great article: http://beerpla.net/2010/01/13/wordpress-plugin-development-how-to-include-css-and-javascript-conditionally-and-only-when-needed-by-the-posts/

But it doesn't take into account multiple calls to the_posts in a single page request :(

**EDIT 2:**

What I've tried is to use:

```
add_action('wp', 'CrayonWP::queue');
```

Since the `wp` action is only used once right after the request is finalised.

And inside this function:

```
global $wp_query;
$posts = $wp_query->posts;
```

I'm not sure how the $wp_query variable changes over the loop however. If the_posts filter is being called again and again, would it imply the original query may be changing as the widgets send across their own requests? Obviously I don't really want to check for shortcodes in the posts of "recent posts", since they may not be displaying on the page at the moment. So will using the `wp` action hook instead of `the_posts` filter contain the posts requested for that given page, whether it were a single or the home page?

Comment: You can call enqueue_script inside the shortcode and add your `<script>`s in the footer (set $in_footer = true)

Comment: problem with CSS loading after DIVs appear though

Comment: Inline CSS? Or just load it unconditionally and suggest the user plugin that concatenates CSS files, like W3TC

Comment: This is old, but just remembered, the codex says you need to have everything ready by wp_header even if you want it in the footer... Adding the CSS includes right before the divs works well.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it, but could [is_main_query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query) (appeared in 3.3) be used here to test that the query being run is the query used to populate 'the Loop'. (I'm not sure how it handles new `WP_Query` instances, though).

The Codex says that it can be used on the `pre_get_posts`, but looking at the code I can't see why it can't be called on a later hook (i.e. `the_posts`)- all it does is check the global `$wp_the_query` against the current query.